# Do forward chaining (Rete) business rules (Drools, ILOG) / production rules support higher order rules and compositionality?

Tags: programming-languages, logic, prolog, higher-order-logic, constraint-handling-rules

There is this talk http://andrewcropper.com/pubs/jelia19-typed.pdf about higher order Prolog, about use of higher-order predicates (that takes other predicates as arguments) and compositionality of predicates. All that is about Prolog and backward chaining inference.

My question is: do business rules (Drools, ILOG), production rules and Rete algorithm support higher order business rules. Simple business rule is:

```
if x=5, then y=6
```

Higher order business rule may be (as I understand, please, correct me, if I am wrong)

```
if rule P fired then rule R comes into force
```

This seems to be quite applied question (more appropriate for stackoverflow), but I am asking this about the possibility of higher order expressivity for production rules and about possibility of Rete algorithm for handling such extensions? Maybe other algorithm is necessary?

I also remember that there was extensive PhdThesis about formal semantics (especially about Hoare logic) for IBM ILOG JRules - that would be great reference here - but I can not find to add it here. If I could gind, I would have added it here to show that business rules/production rules are quite interesting from the computer science (not only programming) point of view as well. And that there are challening issues.